# Xcode 4 и xcode 5 на одной машине

Tags: xcode

как извесно в пятом икскоде файлы .xib строятся иначе. При первом открытии интерфейсного файла собранного в четвертом искоде в пятом он предлагает пересчитать файл в новый формат но предупреждает что в старом виде он больше не будет доступен. у меня ест ь надобность поддерживать полноценно старый проэкт (до iOS7)  в Xcode 4.6.3 и хочется поставить новый Xcode 5 чтобы разрабатывать в нем под ioS7+. Можно ли оставить два икскода на одной машине одновременно или как решить этот вопрос?

Comment: Вам же важнее чтобы код работал правильно в предыдущей версии оси или именно сохранить формат xib файла?

Comment: для проекта о котором идет речь -  сохранить формат xib файла, чтобы можнго было его поддерживать

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я думаю, сохранить обе версии будет непросто. По крайней мере вам понадобятся для этого специальные усилия.

Вопрос - а что мешает вам в ответ на вопрос Xcode 5:

[image: Upgrade to take advantage of Xcode 5 features]

Ответить "Skip"?

Кроме того, наоборот, что мешает вам ответить "Always Upgrade" (я так сделал), и спокойно разрабывать ваш старый проект точно также как и раньше? Все до-iOS7 версии вашего проекта точно также будут собираться и работать в соответствующих симуляторах этих предыдущих версий. Я ни разу ещё не столкнулся с проблемой каких-то несовместимостей именно в связи с апгрейдом Xcode 5. Если вы стокнулись, вам стоит наверное как-то их подробно описать в вашем вопросе.

---

**ОБНОВЛЕНО ПОЗЖЕ**

Если вы так уж сильно опасаетесь проблем с обратной совместимостью - вы можете некоторое время просто "порисковать". Для этого лично я делал бы следующие шаги:

1. Я должен был бы быть уверен, что мой проект очень хорошо находиться под version-контролем, то есть должен находиться в Github- или там Mercurial-дереве.
2. После того, как 1 выполнено. Я делаю "опасный шаг" и нажимаю upgrade/always upgrade. Выхожу из Xcode 5, вхожу в Xcode 4 проверяю, всё ли работает.
3. Если всё работает, коммичу изменения в дерево с соответствующим названием коммита, чтобы потом можно было легко откатиться.
4. В Xcode 5 Делаю изменения в xib или storyboard'ах, опять выхожу в 4, проверяю, коммичу.
5. Делаю шаг 4 до тех пор, пока не убеждаюсь, что реальной опасности нет. А если оказывается, что реально Xcode 5 портит проекты (повторяю, я пока что **ни разу** не видел), возвращаюсь к данному вопросу на ХэшКоде с подробным описанием деталей разбоя Xcode 5.

Кратко: Я думаю (I encourage you), вам нужно набраться смелости и перейти на Xcode 5 и просто какое-то время понаблюдать за своими xib/storyboard-ами в Xcode 4. Для этого вам поможет Git или любая другая система контроля версий.

Этот вариант только с Xcode 5 явно более здоровый и "прогрессивный", чем пытаться ужить два Xcode помимо практики самой Apple.

Удачи!

Comment: я как раз дошел до этого окошка и пошел читать в сеть.пишут что если старые проекты открывать новым икскодом то бьются чxib файлы и в четвертом икскоде потом уже не открываются. побоялся этого и дальше решил не шутить с этми делом

Comment: 1. А что мешает вам вообще остаться без Xcode 4 - зачем он вам? 2. Скорее всего пишут именно про случай, когда выбирается upgrade/always upgrade. По поводу 2 сейчас добавлю в ответ в конец еще соображение.

Comment: Обновил ответ.

Comment: нужно пробывать с изменением и потом обратным откатом  в системе контроля версий

Comment: а вот с контролем версий тоже могут быть проблемы - 4 и 5 используют разные версии свн (гит не проверял, а вот с вн же столкнулся), 5 все время просит обновить репозиторий до нового и если это сделать - он перестанет в 4 (в командлайн тул 4 точно, в гуе не помню), имейте это в виду

Comment: Лично я никогда не пользовался внутренним контролем за Git, который предоставляет Xcode. Старая привычка - все делать руками из консоли, поэтому даже в голову не приходило это учитывать. Но в общем случае, это очень ценное предупреждение, спасибо!

Comment: с Git таких проблем нет.

Answer (score 4):

Ради эксперимента поставил пятый Xcode начисто, потом перетянул четверку из образа в другую папку. Открывал несколько проектов , в том числе обоими версиями одновременно  - проблем не возникло. Единственное о чем стоит помнить, это то что со времен выхода пятого Xcode версии Ваших программ собранных в четверке аппрув гарантированно не пройдут. Так что для коммерческой разработки четверка уже не подходит -  можете смело удалять.